# Как в QLabel одного окна загрузить содержимое *.txt файла, прочитанного в другом окне

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlabel

У меня есть файл, путь к которому я запрашиваю у пользователя. 
Как сделать чтобы содержимое этого файла появлялось в `QLabel`?

Нужно чтобы данные из файла появлялись в `QLabel` в другом окне, при этом окно `MainWindow` закрывалось бы.

У меня есть **`3`** окна. В главном окне есть **`2`** кнопки:

- 1-выбор файла пользователем;
- 2-переход ко 2-ому окну.

Мне нужно чтобы после выбора файла (файл будет в формате pdf), вся информация, которая была в этом файле переносилась в третье окно в `QLabel`.

Код из главного окна **main.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QLabel
from newrules import Ui_Form
from form import *

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def openWindow(self):
        self.window=QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.ui=Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi3(self.window)
        self.window.show()
        MainWindow.hide()
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(763, 544)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(16, 209, 235);\n"
"")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 48, 711, 441))
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.text_zagolovok = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.layoutWidget)
        self.text_zagolovok.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 100))
        self.text_zagolovok.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 100))
        self.text_zagolovok.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(16, 209, 235);")
        self.text_zagolovok.setObjectName("text_zagolovok")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.text_zagolovok)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget, clicked=lambda: self.openWindow())
        self.pushButton_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(350, 150))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(16, 209, 235);")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(350, 150))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(16, 209, 235);")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.addFunc()

    def addFunc(self):
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.write_file)
    def write_file(self):
        res = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()[0]
        f = open(res, "r", -1, "utf-8")
#В этой переменной скопирована вся информация из выбранного файла. Я думаю что ее можно вставить в третье окно в переменную label
        all_f = f.read()
        f.close()
         

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "ГЕНЕРАТОР ТЕСТОВ"))
        self.text_zagolovok.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:18pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:28pt;\">Генератор тестов</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Начать тест"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить файл с тестом"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow =QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Код из второго окна **newrules.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from form import Ui_Form1

class Ui_Form(object):
    def opentest(self):
        self.window1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.ui = Ui_Form1()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window1)
        self.window1.show()

    def setupUi3(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(711, 441)
        Form.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(16, 209, 235)")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(16, 12, 681, 351))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(16, 209, 235);")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.push_btn_starttest = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form, clicked = lambda: self.opentest())
        self.push_btn_starttest.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 370, 181, 61))
        self.push_btn_starttest.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(16, 209, 235);")
        self.push_btn_starttest.setObjectName("push_btn_starttest")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "правила для работы"))
        self.push_btn_starttest.setText(_translate("Form", "Начать тест"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Третье окно **form.py**, текст из выбранного файла должен появиться именно в переменной `QLabel` с названием "label":

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form1(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(715, 639)
        Form.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(16, 209, 235)")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 691, 501))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(16, 209, 235);")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(600, 530, 101, 91))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(16, 209, 235);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 530, 581, 91))
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout_11 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout_11.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_11.setObjectName("verticalLayout_11")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_4)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_5)
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_6)
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_7)
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_8.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_8)
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_9.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_9)
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_10.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_10)
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_11.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_11)
        self.verticalLayout_11.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.radioButton_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_2.setObjectName("radioButton_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton_2)
        self.radioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton.setObjectName("radioButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton)
        self.radioButton_3 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_3.setObjectName("radioButton_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton_3)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.radioButton_4 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_4.setObjectName("radioButton_4")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.radioButton_4)
        self.radioButton_5 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_5.setObjectName("radioButton_5")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.radioButton_5)
        self.radioButton_6 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_6.setObjectName("radioButton_6")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.radioButton_6)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.radioButton_7 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_7.setObjectName("radioButton_7")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.radioButton_7)
        self.radioButton_8 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_8.setObjectName("radioButton_8")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.radioButton_8)
        self.radioButton_9 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_9.setObjectName("radioButton_9")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.radioButton_9)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_3)
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
        self.radioButton_10 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_10.setObjectName("radioButton_10")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.radioButton_10)
        self.radioButton_11 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_11.setObjectName("radioButton_11")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.radioButton_11)
        self.radioButton_12 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_12.setObjectName("radioButton_12")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.radioButton_12)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_4)
        self.verticalLayout_9 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_9.setObjectName("verticalLayout_9")
        self.radioButton_25 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_25.setObjectName("radioButton_25")
        self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.radioButton_25)
        self.radioButton_26 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_26.setObjectName("radioButton_26")
        self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.radioButton_26)
        self.radioButton_27 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_27.setObjectName("radioButton_27")
        self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.radioButton_27)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_9)
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName("verticalLayout_5")
        self.radioButton_13 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_13.setObjectName("radioButton_13")
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.radioButton_13)
        self.radioButton_14 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_14.setObjectName("radioButton_14")
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.radioButton_14)
        self.radioButton_15 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_15.setObjectName("radioButton_15")
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.radioButton_15)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_5)
        self.verticalLayout_10 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_10.setObjectName("verticalLayout_10")
        self.radioButton_28 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_28.setObjectName("radioButton_28")
        self.verticalLayout_10.addWidget(self.radioButton_28)
        self.radioButton_29 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_29.setObjectName("radioButton_29")
        self.verticalLayout_10.addWidget(self.radioButton_29)
        self.radioButton_30 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_30.setObjectName("radioButton_30")
        self.verticalLayout_10.addWidget(self.radioButton_30)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_10)
        self.verticalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_7.setObjectName("verticalLayout_7")
        self.radioButton_19 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_19.setObjectName("radioButton_19")
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.radioButton_19)
        self.radioButton_20 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_20.setObjectName("radioButton_20")
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.radioButton_20)
        self.radioButton_21 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_21.setObjectName("radioButton_21")
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.radioButton_21)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_7)
        self.verticalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_8.setObjectName("verticalLayout_8")
        self.radioButton_22 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_22.setObjectName("radioButton_22")
        self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.radioButton_22)
        self.radioButton_23 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_23.setObjectName("radioButton_23")
        self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.radioButton_23)
        self.radioButton_24 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_24.setObjectName("radioButton_24")
        self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.radioButton_24)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_8)
        self.verticalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_6.setObjectName("verticalLayout_6")
        self.radioButton_16 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_16.setObjectName("radioButton_16")
        self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.radioButton_16)
        self.radioButton_17 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_17.setObjectName("radioButton_17")
        self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.radioButton_17)
        self.radioButton_18 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_18.setObjectName("radioButton_18")
        self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.radioButton_18)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_6)
        self.verticalLayout_11.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "сдесь должен быть текст из выбранного файла"))

        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "кнопка"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "№1"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Form", "№2"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form", "№3"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("Form", "№4"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("Form", "№5"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("Form", "№6"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("Form", "№7"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("Form", "№8"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("Form", "№9"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("Form", "№10"))
        self.radioButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.radioButton_4.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_5.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_6.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.radioButton_7.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_8.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_9.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.radioButton_10.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_11.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_12.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.radioButton_25.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_26.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_27.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.radioButton_13.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_14.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_15.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.radioButton_28.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_29.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_30.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.radioButton_19.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_20.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_21.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.radioButton_22.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_23.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_24.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.radioButton_16.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_17.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_18.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form1()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: flikky, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] или пример, который вы уже написали, который демонстрирует проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, НИКОГДА**. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

Хоте я не уверен, что виджет `QLabel` это то что вам надо, но вам виднее.

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QLabel

from q1496576_newrules import Ui_Form as Ui_NewRules         # + Ui_NewRules
from q1496576_form import  Ui_Form as Ui_OpenTest            # + Ui_OpenTest


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(763, 544)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(16, 209, 235);\n"
"")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 48, 711, 441))
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.text_zagolovok = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.layoutWidget)
        self.text_zagolovok.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 100))
        self.text_zagolovok.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 100))
        self.text_zagolovok.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(16, 209, 235);")
        self.text_zagolovok.setObjectName("text_zagolovok")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.text_zagolovok)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        
# ?      self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget, clicked=lambda: self.openWindow())
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)  

        self.pushButton_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(350, 150))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(16, 209, 235);")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(350, 150))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(16, 209, 235);")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

# ???        self.addFunc()
# ???    def addFunc(self):
# ???        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.write_file)
# ???        
# ???    def write_file(self):
# ???        res = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()[0]
# ???        f = open(res, "r", -1, "utf-8")
# В этой переменной скопирована вся информация из выбранного файла. 
# Я думаю что ее можно вставить в третье окно в переменную label
# ???        all_f = f.read()
# ???        f.close()
         

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "ГЕНЕРАТОР ТЕСТОВ"))
        self.text_zagolovok.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:18pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:28pt;\">Генератор тестов</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Начать тест"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить файл с тестом"))


# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class OpenTest(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_OpenTest):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
  
  
class NewRules(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_NewRules):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
    

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.write_file)
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.start_test)
# ----> vvvv <---------------------------------------------------- # !!! +++        
        self.all_f = None                                          # !!! +++
        
    def write_file(self):
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self,
            'Open File',
            '',
            '*.txt'
        )
        if not fileName:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'Внимание', 'Добавте файл с тестом')
            return
            
        with open(fileName, "r", -1, "utf-8") as f: 
#        f = open(res, "r", -1, "utf-8")
# В этой переменной скопирована вся информация из выбранного файла. 
# Я думаю что ее можно вставить в третье окно в переменную label

            self.all_f = f.read()                                   # !!! +++

#           f.close()        

    def start_test(self):
        if not self.all_f:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'Внимание', 'Добавте файл с тестом')        
            return        
        self.newRules = NewRules()
        self.newRules.push_btn_starttest.clicked.connect(self.open_test)
        self.newRules.show()
        self.hide()        

    def open_test(self):
        self.openTest = OpenTest()
        self.openTest.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.open_test_clicked)
        self.openTest.label.setText(f'{self.all_f}')
        self.openTest.show()   
        self.newRules.hide() 
        
    def open_test_clicked(self):
        print(f'def open_test_clicked(self): \n{self.all_f}') # 
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**q1496576_newrules.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
#from q1496576_form import Ui_Form1

class Ui_Form(object):
# ?    def setupUi3(self, Form):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(711, 441)
        Form.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(16, 209, 235)")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(16, 12, 681, 351))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(16, 209, 235);")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        
# ?      self.push_btn_starttest = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form, clicked = lambda: self.opentest())
        self.push_btn_starttest = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)        
        
        self.push_btn_starttest.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 370, 181, 61))
        self.push_btn_starttest.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(16, 209, 235);")
        self.push_btn_starttest.setObjectName("push_btn_starttest")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "правила для работы"))
        self.push_btn_starttest.setText(_translate("Form", "Начать тест"))
```

**q1496576_form.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

#class Ui_Form1(object):
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(715, 639)
        Form.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(16, 209, 235)")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 691, 501))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(16, 209, 235);")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(600, 530, 101, 91))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(16, 209, 235);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 530, 581, 91))
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout_11 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout_11.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_11.setObjectName("verticalLayout_11")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_4)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_5)
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_6)
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_7)
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_8.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_8)
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_9.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_9)
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_10.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_10)
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_11.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_11)
        self.verticalLayout_11.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.radioButton_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_2.setObjectName("radioButton_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton_2)
        self.radioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton.setObjectName("radioButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton)
        self.radioButton_3 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_3.setObjectName("radioButton_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton_3)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.radioButton_4 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_4.setObjectName("radioButton_4")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.radioButton_4)
        self.radioButton_5 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_5.setObjectName("radioButton_5")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.radioButton_5)
        self.radioButton_6 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_6.setObjectName("radioButton_6")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.radioButton_6)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.radioButton_7 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_7.setObjectName("radioButton_7")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.radioButton_7)
        self.radioButton_8 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_8.setObjectName("radioButton_8")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.radioButton_8)
        self.radioButton_9 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_9.setObjectName("radioButton_9")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.radioButton_9)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_3)
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
        self.radioButton_10 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_10.setObjectName("radioButton_10")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.radioButton_10)
        self.radioButton_11 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_11.setObjectName("radioButton_11")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.radioButton_11)
        self.radioButton_12 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_12.setObjectName("radioButton_12")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.radioButton_12)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_4)
        self.verticalLayout_9 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_9.setObjectName("verticalLayout_9")
        self.radioButton_25 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_25.setObjectName("radioButton_25")
        self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.radioButton_25)
        self.radioButton_26 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_26.setObjectName("radioButton_26")
        self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.radioButton_26)
        self.radioButton_27 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_27.setObjectName("radioButton_27")
        self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.radioButton_27)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_9)
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName("verticalLayout_5")
        self.radioButton_13 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_13.setObjectName("radioButton_13")
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.radioButton_13)
        self.radioButton_14 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_14.setObjectName("radioButton_14")
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.radioButton_14)
        self.radioButton_15 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_15.setObjectName("radioButton_15")
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.radioButton_15)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_5)
        self.verticalLayout_10 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_10.setObjectName("verticalLayout_10")
        self.radioButton_28 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_28.setObjectName("radioButton_28")
        self.verticalLayout_10.addWidget(self.radioButton_28)
        self.radioButton_29 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_29.setObjectName("radioButton_29")
        self.verticalLayout_10.addWidget(self.radioButton_29)
        self.radioButton_30 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_30.setObjectName("radioButton_30")
        self.verticalLayout_10.addWidget(self.radioButton_30)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_10)
        self.verticalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_7.setObjectName("verticalLayout_7")
        self.radioButton_19 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_19.setObjectName("radioButton_19")
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.radioButton_19)
        self.radioButton_20 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_20.setObjectName("radioButton_20")
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.radioButton_20)
        self.radioButton_21 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_21.setObjectName("radioButton_21")
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.radioButton_21)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_7)
        self.verticalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_8.setObjectName("verticalLayout_8")
        self.radioButton_22 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_22.setObjectName("radioButton_22")
        self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.radioButton_22)
        self.radioButton_23 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_23.setObjectName("radioButton_23")
        self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.radioButton_23)
        self.radioButton_24 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_24.setObjectName("radioButton_24")
        self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.radioButton_24)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_8)
        self.verticalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_6.setObjectName("verticalLayout_6")
        self.radioButton_16 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_16.setObjectName("radioButton_16")
        self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.radioButton_16)
        self.radioButton_17 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_17.setObjectName("radioButton_17")
        self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.radioButton_17)
        self.radioButton_18 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_18.setObjectName("radioButton_18")
        self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.radioButton_18)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_6)
        self.verticalLayout_11.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "сдесь должен быть текст из выбранного файла"))
        
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "кнопка"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "№1"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Form", "№2"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form", "№3"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("Form", "№4"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("Form", "№5"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("Form", "№6"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("Form", "№7"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("Form", "№8"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("Form", "№9"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("Form", "№10"))
        self.radioButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.radioButton_4.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_5.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_6.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.radioButton_7.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_8.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_9.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.radioButton_10.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_11.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_12.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.radioButton_25.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_26.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_27.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.radioButton_13.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_14.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_15.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.radioButton_28.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_29.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_30.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.radioButton_19.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_20.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_21.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.radioButton_22.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_23.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_24.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.radioButton_16.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_17.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_18.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо большое, ты меня очень сильно выручил

Comment: @flikky пожалуйста.  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour